# Running spl-token initialize-metadata getting error

Tags: solana-cli

Syntax:

spl-token initialize-metadata Bk8e....xyzK "NAME of Token" "SYMBOL" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxx/TOKEN.json" --url https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

I've tried so many times with different methods but it keeps failing. I've tried python with another method but keep getting method not found using update-metadata.

Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xc", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(1, Custom(12))), logs: Some(["Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]", "Program log: Error: Invalid instruction", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 863 of 399850 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0xc"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(150), return_data: None }) }) })

Answer (score 1):

Your token was created against `spl-token`, and not `spl-token-2022`. Only `spl-token-2022` supports metadata inside the mint.

You can create a token with metadata on `spl-token-2022` using the following command:

```
$ spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --enable-metadata
```

After that, your command will work.